# Why does my Stack Exchange account show a lower answer number compared with my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, statistics

[image]

Why does this occur?

Comment: Caching. It's always caching...

Comment: @Yannis I visited in separate browsers and same difference. Is it a server cache or client cache?

Comment: @hallaji: I'd imagine it's caching it on the server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of less critical items that are heavily cached server-side for performance sake (one of the reasons the site is as fast as it is).

Between today and yesterday, you answered 5 questions, so that appears to be the difference.  If it doesn't update soon, to at least reflect your posts from yesterday, then I would suggest waiting a little longer.  Eventually it will update, but because of the caching, if you want them to match, the only solution will be to take a couple of days off from answering ;-)

Comment: Discontinuing usage of stack overflow for any reason is not recommended

Comment: @RichardTingle at least without being under a doctor's supervision

Comment: The doctor must have ready an emergency tablet... with Stack preloaded...

Comment: @psubsee2003 Funny :) But I think it is a little strange! Because of reputations and badges are synced without caching. Maybe there are set to no cache...

Comment: @hallaji virtually all of the calculated fields are cached, some are updated more frequently. Caching is a trade off for the site performance, and it something I think most frequent users will happily accept.